# jQuery mobile 1.2: Override opacity of .ui-disabled

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am trying to override the opacity of `ui-disabled` in my app to have a **not focusable textfield with white text**  that i can change per js (`<disabled="true">`).

i don't know if it will work on all browsers with the `opacity` set to `1`

or how to use the suggestion on this page exactly (on mobileinit or as a css-file and how about the semantics):
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html

Comment: Possibly something like: .ui-disabled { color:red !important; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override jQuery Mobile's CSS with your own. Include a stylesheet *after* jqm's in your html, or use a `style=...` attribute on your html tag — either will override the default. Hence the **Cascading** in **Cascading Style Sheets**.

I highly recommend using the developer tools built into most browsers. In Chrome, for example, right-click anything in a web page and select Inspect Element. It will show you the computed CSS for the element, including which styles came from which CSS file, which were overridden by other stylesheets, etc. You can even edit the styles in the tool and see what changes would look like.

Here you can see the stylesheet f.css overrides several properties from the jqm stylesheet, which sets them in several places and overrides itself with various classes:

[image: css inspector]

Comment: Thank you - I was able to find the sheet i`ve searched for via chrome! great!